# Rigify in Blender 2.79

Tags: rigify

I don´t like the rigify in Blender 2.79. I think it generates too much complicated controls and whenever I had to rig a character I have to open the file in an older version, play the rigify generator and then i re-open in 2.79 to continue the work. Especially for the fingers rigging, the old one is way better than this new version. Is there any other method to use the old friendly rigify in version 2.79? Thanks

Comment: Are you changing limbs.simple_tentacle to limbs.super_finger in Rigify Type properties? If not do that, and you'll have the good, nice finger controls.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the 1 year old response...

Answer (score 2):

The Rigify add-on still has the option to run in legacy mode (2.76b feature set) if you check the option under the User Preferences > Add-ons > Rigify. This also still rings true in the Blender 2.8 Beta.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry that it took forever to thank you..